# get parameter from response API

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, api, codeigniter

I got a problem when retrieving the parameters of the response. Anyone can help? :(

this error on console :

> katalog_laporan:1837 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MENU'
>   of undefined
>       at Object. (katalog_laporan:1837)
>       at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:359)
>       at Object.success (katalog_laporan:1830)
>       at j (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:3152)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:3212)
>       at x (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:8159)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:8159)

this file js me :

```
                for(x = 0; x <= panjangindex; x++){
                    var fullmenu = response.detail[x].MENU;
                    var itemmenu = fullmenu.split('>');
                    var jumlahitem = itemmenu.length;
                    el.append('<li>');
                       for(i = 0; i < jumlahitem; i++){
                           var item = itemmenu[i]; 
                           el.append('<span  style="font-size:12px" class="label label-info arrowed-right arrowed-in">'+itemmenu[i]+'</span>');  
                       }
                    el.append('</li><br><br>');   
                }
```

Comment: it means the key `MENU` in the object `response.detail[x]` doesn't exist. check your ajax response to see what it looks like. Post the controller code and the response. If you don't provide either then nobody can help.

Comment: You might also want to tell us what `panjangindex` is set to because if its set to the array length of `response.detail`, then the right statement should be `for(x = 0; x < panjangindex; x++){` with `<` not `<=`

Comment: @Alex Here I only manage this response to display to view : {  "details": [{" ID_REPORT  ": "1", "  ID_MENU  ": "481 ", " LAST_MENU ":   "," loan "MENU  ":  "DWH Reports > Report > Fixed Loan  ", "LINK": "  Reportlist  /index/481 "}]}

Comment: why do you need a loop if there is only one item?

Comment: @Alex because in one column there are many menus, I wanted to split the menu. and I don't know the name of the original column. I just manage it via the API

Comment: that might explain your 2nd for but not the first where the issue seems to lie. in any case it would be better to show your full js for this function as some variables declarations aren't shown.

Comment: @Alex thank you I've found the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try like that --

```
response.detail[x]['MENU']
```

instead of --

```
response.detail[x].MENU
```

If still not works then please share response variable format via below link.

https://gist.github.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid showing this error you should check availability of you object or array so it will be like**

```
for(x = 0; x <= panjangindex; x++){
var fullmenu = response.detail[x].MENU ?     response.detail[x].MENU : null;

if(fullmenu) {
    var itemmenu = fullmenu.split('>');
    var jumlahitem = itemmenu.length;
    el.append('<li>');
    for(i = 0; i < jumlahitem; i++){
        var item = itemmenu[i]; 
        el.append('<span  style="font-size:12px" class="label label-info arrowed-right arrowed-in">'+itemmenu[i]+'</span>');  
    }
el.append('</li><br><br>');
}
}
```

And you have to check your api call that its already containing this element by console.log(response.details[x]);